# NBR and Surface reflectance

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro

I'm mapping the forest fire event in ArcGIS Pro and created NBR and dNBR to see the severity, using Landsat 8. The way I did it is with bands 5 and 7, through raster calculator NBR = (Band 5 – Band 7) / (Band 5 + Band 7) and for dNBR did NBRpre-NBRpost. But the result seems wrong to me because when I try to classify it in the symbology, the highest value (high severity) is 0,58 whereas in the table [here](https://un-spider.org/advisory-support/recommended-practices/recommended-practice-burn-severity/in-detail/normalized-burn-ratio), the highest is <0,66. After some googling, I learned about the term Surface Reflectance and apparently you need to correct image reflectance but I could not find how.

Now my question is do I have to conduct surface reflectance thing on my images, if yes how? Is what I did with the help of raster calculator wrong? As a beginner I find it a little bit confusing.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Is Landsat collection 1 or 2?

If you are using collection 1, no need to convert DN to reflectance for computing normalized difference indices (like NBR) since it has a scale factor of 0.0001 with no offset.

This is different from collection 2. This collection has a 0.0000275 scale factor and a -0.2 offset. For this case, you should compute reflectance using these values:

```
Reflectance = 0.0000275*DN - 0.2
```

Why? Imagine a L8 Col1 pixel with the following values:

```
DN NIR: 5000
DN SWIR: 2000

NBR = (5000 - 2000)/(5000 + 2000)
NBR = .429
```

Computing reflectance, the output is the same:

```
Refl. NIR: .5
Refl. SWIR: .2

NBR = (.5 - .2)/(.5 + .2)
NBR = .429
```

For Col2:

```
DN NIR: 30000
DN SWIR: 20000

NBR = (30000 - 20000)/(30000 + 20000)
NBR = .2
```

After computing reflectance, the output changes:

```
Refl. NIR: .625
Refl. SWIR: .35

NBR = (.625 - .35)/(.625 + .35)
NBR = .282
```